# Is there a shorter and/or more efficient way to utilize arrays in conditional statements? (in this case the "if" statement)

Tags: python, arrays, performance, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
count = 0
vowels = "aeiou"
open("TEXT FILE PATH", "r") as text:
    text = text.read()
for character in range(len(text) - 1):
    if text[(character + 1) and (character - 1)] not in vowels and text[character] in vowels:
        count += 1
```

In the above "if statement" I am trying to check if the string in front of and behind "character" are not vowels while minimizing the length of my conditional but in Python this doesn't work while the line below does.

```
if text[character] in vowels and text[(character + 1)] not in vowels and text[character - 1] not in vowels:
```

Basically the idea is not have 3 mile long code like the line above. Is there another approach to this code that could make this shorter and/or more efficient?

Comment: indexing into a string by `text[(character + 1) and (character - 1)] ` is not how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The physical meaning of the code in the question is to perforem counting if there is no vowel before and after, which means, any consecutive vowels should be considered as one in counting.
Therefore, we can write your code in an effecient way and get the same result:

```
open("TEXT FILE PATH", "r") as text:
    text = text.read()
    count=len(re.findall(r'[aeiouAEIOU](?![aeiouAEIOU])',text))
```

in the regular expression `[aeiouAEIOU](?![aeiouAEIOU])`, it selects any vowel in the list, in case of that vowel does not have another one after. Then, we get the number of them by using the function `len()`

*example* for the text `neat retreat`

```
import re
text='neat retreat'
count=len(re.findall(r'[aeiouAEIOU](?![aeiouAEIOU])',text))
print(count)
```

output:

```
3
```

for more calrification

```
import re
text='retreat'
count=len(re.findall(r'[aeiouAEIOU](?![aeiouAEIOU])',text))
print(count)
```

output

```
2
```

Comment: This would match the second vowel of a pair, though, which the OP doesn't want.

Comment: Maybe add a negative look behind `(?<![aeiouAEIOU])[aeiouAEIOU](?![aeiouAEIOU])`?

Comment: @wwii  we need to count, and not to get the letter itself, so the result is the same.

Comment: @Thierry I added an example. I will be grateful if you explain your comment by a text example.

Comment: The last, working example the OP gives in his question shows that he wants to count vowels that are neither preceded nor followed by a vowel. In your example, only the first 'e' in 'retreat' would satisfy these conditions.

Comment: @Thierry, but if we consider text='retreat', the result will be `2` as I posted again in the answer.

Comment: @wwii in the mention case, `(?<![aeiouAEIOU])[aeiouAEIOU](?![aeiouAEIOU])`, `(?<![aeiouAEIOU])[aeiouAEIOU]` or `[aeiouAEIOU](?![aeiouAEIOU])` gives the save counting number.

Comment: It should be 1: only the first 'e' that is between consonants 'r' and 't'. The second 'e' is followed by the vowel 'a', so not good, and the 'a' is preceded by the vowel 'e', so not good either.

Comment: @Thierry let us try to run both the codes, in the question and in the answer and compare the results.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille The physical meaning of the code in the question is to perforem counting if there is no vowel before and after, which means, any consecutive vowels should be considered as one in counting.

Comment: Thanks! By reading the code and the comments I figured out how to find any number of  vowels trapped between two consonants.

Answer (score 0):

You can create all 3-len parts of your text and use `all()` to check:

```
count = 0
vowels = set("aeiou")

text = """All your bases belong to us if you can read this"""

parts = [text[p:p+3] for p in range(len(text)-3)]

# get the total count
count += sum( all(p[k] not in vowels for k in (0,2)) for p in parts)

# or print whats been counted
for p in parts:
    if all(p[w] not in vowels for w in [0,2]):
        print(p)

print(count)
```

Output:

```
All
ll 
l y
r b
bas
ses
s b
bel
lon
ng 
g t
to 
 us
 if
f y
can
n r
d t
 th
19
```